# Spring Integration Support lifetime

Tags: spring-integration

We are in the design phase of a new application JMS based application. We were thinking of making use of spring-integration-jms. Had one question about the planned support that will be provided for spring-integration-jms in future for any security vulnerabilities and other stuff that might appear in future.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like such a question makes sense over here on StackOverflow, but being a project lead I can answer you.

As long as JMS spec is not deprecated and supported in Java EE, we are going to support and maintain `spring-integration-jms` module. In fact in the current `6.0` version we even have moved to `jakarta.jms` namespace.

For more support questions, please, reach out here: https://spring.io/support